# how to compute the big O of sort and then merge

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, big-o, time-complexity

if I sort in O(m+n) complexity and then mergesort in O(nlogn) complexity, is it over all the sum or the most significant complexity?

Comment: Most significant. Whichever grows faster.

Comment: I think you mean sort() followed by merge(). Merge() is O(n). Sort() could be O(n log(n)). Since the O(n) is just a constant factor, then the overall would still be O(n log(n)).

Comment: Welcome to SO, dardi! Since you are (relatively) new, you might want to check this [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 0):

They are both independent from each other. Then `(m + n) + nlogn = O(n logn)`  since `n logn` is little faster than linear time.